# How to delete s suffix in module from laraadmin (in Module Name and DB table name) - Laravel Project

Tags: laravel, laraadmin

I have a laraadmin project.
But; laraadmin puts the s suffix of module names and module db tables.
Example.

I created new module. This module name is : "setting"

if i create module from this name, then the module name becomes the settings.

I want to remove it.(s suffix)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i solved this problem.

find in project dir :

....\vendor\dwij\laraadmin\src\Models\Module.php

find in this file :

```
    public static function generateModuleNames($module_name, $icon) {
    $array = array();
    $module_name = trim($module_name);
    $module_name = str_replace(" ", "_", $module_name);

    $array['module'] = ucfirst($module_name);               // OLD = $array['module'] = ucfirst(str_plural($module_name));
    $array['label'] = ucfirst($module_name);                // OLD = ucfirst(str_plural($module_name)); 
    $array['table'] = strtolower($module_name);             // OLD = strtolower(str_plural($module_name));
    $array['model'] = ucfirst(str_singular($module_name));
    $array['fa_icon'] = $icon;
    $array['controller'] = $array['module']."Controller";
    $array['singular_l'] = strtolower(str_singular($module_name));
    $array['singular_c'] = ucfirst(str_singular($module_name));

    return (object) $array;
}
```

get rid of this function : str_plural();